# "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

Tags: matlab

I am creating a MATLAB code to estimate the Jacobian matrix using forward differences. Here is the code:

```
%Calculate Jacobian Numerically using forward differences:
function J=Jacobianest(x,F) % X is a column vector of variables, f is a   column function vector
h=1e-7;
n=length(x);
J=zeros(n);
for i=1:n
    xp=x;
    xp(i)=x(i)+h;
    J(:,i)=1/h*(F(xp)-F(x));
end
```

When I run it the following error appears:

```
Jacobianest(x,'multivariable_newton_fun')
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in Jacobianest (line 9)
J(:,i)=1/h*(F(xp)-F(x));
```

I looked at other questions for answers and tried debugging/`dbstop`, but I can't seem to find anything obvious.

I am using `i` as the column index which should just have integer values from `1` to `n` (all integers hopefully).

Comment: The error is not in the assignment to `J`, but in the assignment to `F`. I guess `xp` and `x` are not integers. I think `F(xp(i))` would solve your problem. As an additional suggestion: [don't use `i` as a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function not a string.
How about:

```
Jacobianest(x,@multivariable_newton_fun)
```

If it's a string, i.e. you use single-quotes, then `F(1)` gives the first letter of the name the string, in this case 'm'.
Also if you try `F(0)` you'll get the above error.

The `@` generates a function (think of a function handle, or a function reference, in other languages). Then the parentheses `F(xp)` are interpreted as a function call, rather than subscript indices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very useful. I've sorted it now.